# Add html_strip filter to Text field

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to add the html_strip filter to my "title" ad "description" fields which are of type text. Basically trying to remove html tags before indexing my data

Here is my mapping :

```
 {
   "settings":{
      "number_of_shards":1,
      "index": {
      "analysis": {
        "char_filter": {
          "ignore_html_tags": {
            "type": "html_strip"
          }
        },
        "analyzer": {
          "ignore_html_tags": {
            "tokenizer": "lowercase",
            "char_filter": [
              "ignore_html_tags"
            ],
            "type": "custom"
          }
        }
      }
    }
   },
   "mappings":{
      "dynamic":"strict",
      "properties":{
         "title":{
            "type":"text",
            "analyzer": "ignore_html_tags",
            "fields":{
               "keyword":{
                  "type":"keyword"
               }
            }
         },
         "description":{
            "type":"text",
            "analyzer": "ignore_html_tags",
            "fields":{
               "keyword":{
                  "type":"keyword"
               }
            }
         },
         "url":{
            "type":"keyword"
         },
         "type":{
            "type":"keyword"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Im adding this entry to the index :

```
    {
    "title": "<p>I&apos;m so <b>happy</b>!</p>",
    "description": "<p>I&apos;m so <b>happy</b>!</p>",
    "type":"article",
    "url":"https://google.com"
}
```

When I check my index, the fields still have the HTML tags. Im getting this response, using this query :

Query :

```
   {
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "description": {
        "query": "happy"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Response :

```
"_id": "fvHFooYB3c8yA-Odufss",
                "_score": 0.18232156,
                "_source": {
                    "title": "<p>I&apos;m so <b>happy</b>!</p>",
                    "description": "<p>I&apos;m so <b>happy</b>!</p>",
                    "type": "article",
                    "url": "https://google.com"
                }
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

you're doing nothing wrong, I guess you only have the wrong expectation. The analyzer doesn't prevent elasticsearch from writing HTML tags in those document fields, but will allow you at query time to replace those HTML tags with their decoded value. Therefore, in your example, you could search for

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "description": {
        "query": "I'm"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and get a result although the actual field value is `<p>I&apos;m so <b>happy</b>!</p>`

Comment: Oh alright.
Is there a way to acheive what I want to do ? Meaning strip the fields from the tag values before indexing them ?

Comment: yes, you may want to look into ingest pipelines, HTML strip processor: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/htmlstrip-processor.html